# Quartz scheduler and programmatically setting datasource

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I'm integrating Quartz into my application and wondering if there is a way to set up my scheduler with a DataSource that I already have configured and at hand? Do I need to use the SchedulerFactory somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement [ConnectionProvider](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/utils/ConnectionProvider.html)

And specify property **org.quartz.dataSource.standalone.connectionProvider.class** in quart.properties

for ex :
org.quartz.dataSource.standalone.connectionProvider.class = com.mycompany.CustomConnectionProvider

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @Javadroider answer, you have to have a ConnectionProvider implementation and have configured quartz to instantiate it.
"After instantiating the class, Quartz can automatically set configuration properties on the instance, bean-style". This means you have to have fields on your properties, and setters for them; quartz will take care of calling the setters.

Ex:

`public class FooConnectionProvider implements ConnectionProvider {`

```
private String connectionString;

@Override 
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return null;
}

@Override 
public void shutdown() throws SQLException {

}

@Override public void initialize() throws SQLException {

}

public void setConnectionString(String connectionString) {
    this.connectionString = connectionString;
}
```

}

properties file:

`org.quartz.dataSource.myCustomDS.connectionProvider.class = com.foo.FooConnectionProvider
org.quartz.dataSource.myCustomDS.connectionString=connectionString`